# How do find out how many lines, words, and characters in a file?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I want to write a function that returns a triple "(a,b,c)" of integers, where a is the number of lines in the file, b is the number of words in the file, and c is the number of characters in the file.

I am new to files and I am not sure how to do this. This is what the file contains in case you cannot view it:

It was high time to go, for the pool was getting quite crowded with the birds and animals that had fallen into it: there were a Duck and a Dodo,
a Lory and an Eaglet, and several other curious creatures. Alice led the
way, and the whole party swam to the shore.

```
def get_data(filename):
    '''get_data(filename) -> (int,int,int)
    returns (# of lines,# of words,# of chars) in filename'''
    inFile = open('alice.txt', 'r')
    text = inFile.read()

    lines = len(filename.split('.'))
    words = len(filename.split(' '))
    chars = len(filename)

    return lines, words, chars

print(get_data('alice.txt'))
# should print (4, 52, 262)
```

In my example, it should print 4, 52, and 262 -- There are actually 4 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file:

```
f = open("../data/alice.txt", "r")
txt = f.read()
```

Get the number of sentences:

```
len(txt.split('.'))
3
```

Get the number of words:

```
len(txt.split(' '))
52
```

Get the number of characters:

```
len(txt)
261
```

I'll leave the rest of the function up to you.

Comment: I wrote a function using the above code, but my output was (2, 1, 9) instead of (4, 52, 262).

Comment: yeah, I see there was a typo in the original answer, I've fixed that.